# Docker build ARG always empty string

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile here:

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine as build
ARG DIR=somevalue
RUN echo $DIR
```

Output is

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  57.37MB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:1.13-alpine as build
 ---> 2e384b27f926
Step 2/3 : ARG DIR=somevalue
 ---> Running in 3cd3457a795f
Removing intermediate container 3cd3457a795f
 ---> ecfa2f50c4fa
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $DIR
 ---> Running in aab4e31e0e14

Removing intermediate container aab4e31e0e14
 ---> 5351cb77c245
Successfully built 5351cb77c245
```

DIR is always empty when I try DIR to another name example DIR1 it is empty too.
Docker version is here

```
 Client:

 Version:           18.09.8
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.11
 Git commit:        2c0a67b
 Built:             Fri Sep  6 02:50:44 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:

 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.11
  Git commit:       1d8275b
  Built:            Fri Sep  6 02:51:05 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

However, when I try to another machine, it is right, it will echo some value. Who can give me some tips to find the problem about the wrong machine? thanks.

Comment: Output from what? Please include your build command.

Comment: Did you work this out?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 17):

This is obviously not the problem in your example, but I got this error when declaring an `ARG` before the `FROM`. Moving the `ARG` I needed below `FROM` resolved the problem.

Comment: Me too. I found the explanation [here](https://benkyriakou.com/posts/docker-args-empty). The relevant part of the documentation is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running by passing the `--no-cache` option, it is working as expected for me

```
❯❯❯ docker build . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  194.7MB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:1.13-alpine as build
 ---> 2e384b27f926
Step 2/3 : ARG DIR=somevalue
 ---> Running in c53bbb64dda1
Removing intermediate container c53bbb64dda1
 ---> b76b21aca433
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $DIR
 ---> Running in 6c49d289e258
somevalue
Removing intermediate container 6c49d289e258
 ---> d51e5579f1cb
Successfully built d51e5579f1cb
```

However, if it has built the same image once, it will not output anything as it has the layer cached:

```
❯❯❯ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  194.7MB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:1.13-alpine as build
 ---> 2e384b27f926
Step 2/3 : ARG DIR=somevalue
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b76b21aca433
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $DIR
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d51e5579f1cb
Successfully built d51e5579f1cb
```